# Retrieve mails of only one specific account with fetchmail

Tags: email, fetchmail

### The situation

I have the following `~/.fetchmailrc`

```
poll pop.gmail.com       protocol pop3 user "foo@example.com"      password "***"            ssl
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d default -a foo@example-com"

poll pop.gmail.com       protocol pop3 user "bar@example.com"      password "***"            ssl
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d default -a bar@example-com"
```

So, I retrieve all the mails with `fetchmail -v -m '/usr/bin/procmail -d %T'`.

### The problem

But the problem is all the accounts are retrieved.

### The question

Is it possible from fetchmail command to ask for retrieving just one specific addresses’ mails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give each account a different name and use the `via` option

eg

```
poll foo via pop.gmail.com ...

poll bar via pop.gmail.com ...
```

Now you can specify each one on the command line; `fetchmail foo` will only fetch mail for that one account.

I use this type of structure for Outlook:

```
poll outlook via imap-mail.outlook.com port 993
  proto IMAP
  user my_user_1@outlook.com is foo here
  fetchall
  password *****
  ssl

poll outlook2 via imap-mail.outlook.com port 993
  proto IMAP
  user my_user_2@outlook.com is bar here
  fetchall
  password *****
  ssl
```

This can be implemented as follows in zsh.

##### Alias and function to retrieve mail

```bash
alias retrieveallmails="fetchmail -v -m '/usr/bin/procmail -d %T'" # For all the accounts

function retrievemail()
{
    # For a specific account
    fetchmail $1 -v -m '/usr/bin/procmail -d %T'
}
```

##### Related completion

```bash
_retrievemail_complete() {
    local accounts
    accounts=($(fetchmail --configdump | sed -n 's/.*"pollname":"\(.*\)",/\1/p'))


    _arguments \
        '1: :->account' \
        '*:: :->arguments'

    case $state in
        (account)
            _describe 'accounts' accounts
            ;;
        (arguments)
            _files
            ;;
    esac
}

compdef _retrievemail_complete retrievemail
```

Comment: Just one more question. Is it possible to ask fetchmail to give a list of all accounts names? As example in your case, it could be someting like « outlook,outlook2… ».

Comment: It works with `grep -E "poll\s+\w+\s+via" ~/.fetchmailrc | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ', ' | sed 's/, $//'` but it still hacky.

Comment: I don't know of an official way of doing it, but you could use `--configdump` and a simple `sed`; eg  `fetchmail --configdump | sed -n 's/.*"pollname":"\(.*\)",/\1/p'`.  The output is meant to be python parsable, so you could write a python script to report what you need.